# MVC Hiding label and showing placeholder with EditorForModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following view model class:

```
public class RegistrationViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Prompt = "Email" )]
    public string Login { get; set; }
}
```

And this template

```
@model  System.String

@Html.TextBox("", ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue, 
              new { @class="form_text", 
                    placeholder = ViewData.ModelMetadata.Watermark
                                      ?? ViewData.ModelMetadata.DisplayName
                                      ?? ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName})
```

How do I go about hiding the label?